Function overload resolution for template type parameters with respect to references and pointers
I've been working on some code as an exercise.
template <typename T> const T& larger(const T& a, const T& b) {
    std::cout << "Calling larger(const T&, const T&)" << std::endl;
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

template <typename T> const T* larger(const T* a, const T* b) {

    std::cout << "Calling larger(const T*, const T*)" << std::endl;

    return *a > *b ? a : b;
}

int main() {


    int a { 1 }, b { 2 };
    std::cout << larger(a, b) << std::endl;

    int *c { new int { 5 } }, *d { new int { 4 } };

    std::cout << *larger<int>(c, d) << std::endl;

    return 0;

}

There are a few things I don't understand. Primarily, why does the compiler resolve both calls to the larger() function in main to the template that accepts reference parameters. In the second call to larger shouldn't the deduced types be int* and therefore, call the function that accepts pointer parameters instead?
I do know that I can "fix" my issue by calling the second function with an explicit type parameter larger<int>(c, d) (it works, but I don't know why). However, I am more interested in understanding the type deduction rules for this scenario?

T can be a pointer or any other compound type, you can't overload like that without constraints or SFINAE

OT: There's no need for the dynamic allocation here. Just use the pointer-to operator & to get a pointer. Like &a which will have the type int*.

@Swift-FridayPie However, for const pointers it will resolve to the pointer variation. So the qualifiers do matter right?

What exactly do you mean?  larger(&a, &b) would result in same call to reference variant, note , you can bin non-const reference ora pointer to non-const to a  const reference or pointer to const. Thing is that you get const int *& larger(const int *& ,const int *&);

Value gathegory matters. If you mean  if  arguments ar pointer to const (const int *a ) yes, second versin is preferable because how considering an overload works,  it would consider it a less conversions variant. In original case calls results in conversion of  an lvalue int* to const int*&  vs. to const int*. It's not a problem of templates. Remove template code and make function using int instead of T. same result.

In fact, it's not a problem at all, it's how binding argumend during copy work. An lvalue or xvalue of type T can be bound to a const T& before T. Xvalue would prefer T&& before that. prvalue would prefer T


Primarily, why does the compiler resolve both calls to the larger() function in main to the template that accepts reference parameters?

In larger(a, b), it's obvious: you cannot deduce const T* from the given ints; they're not pointers, so only the first overload is viable.
In the actual larger<int>(c, d), the first overload would have const int& parameters after substituting int, and you cannot bind const int& to pointers, so only the second overload (with int* parameters) is viable.
In a hypothetical larger(c, d), the parameters in the first overload are int * const & (reference to const pointer to int) and this type is reference-compatible with the given int*s.
Therefore, the reference binds directly according to [dcl.init.ref] p5.1.1
without any implicit conversions.
On the other hand, converting int* to const int* for the second overload would require a qualification conversion, which makes this overload worse.
In overload resolution, the overload with the better conversion sequence wins, and here, an Identity is better than Qualification Adjustment (see [tab:over.ics.scs]).
Workaround
There are multiple ways around this dilemma:

Have only one function template containing if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>) ... which handles both cases.
Constrain the first overload with requires !std::is_pointer_v<T>.
...


First look at what is deduced when you pass an lvalue pointer to int.
The first becomes
template<T=int*>
int * const& larger(int* const&, int*const&);

the second becomes
template<T=int>
int const* larger(int const*, int const*);

(I am using east-const style uniformly because it is clearer: the part of the type that is modified by const is left of the const keyword.)
Deciding between a const& to an exact type match, and an impliciy conversion to a more const pointer, the reference to const of an exact type match wins.
You can avoid this a number of ways.  You can block T being a pointer in the first template overload using either a requires clause or sfinae.  In addition, you could ensure that the second one is a strict restriction on the first.
The last annoying problem with your code is that if you pass prvalues you get a dangling reference.
Myself, I'd split larger from compare.  Then do
template<class T>
T larger(T&& a,T&& b){
  if (compare(a,b))
    return std::forward<T>(a);
  else
    return std::forward<T>(b);
}

now compare has to worry about comparing pointers vs non pointers, but not about returnong dangling references or not.
(A fancier larger handles one being a prvalue and another not using something like std common type).

Case 1
For the first calls larger(a,b), only the first version larger(const T& a, const T& b) is viable and so is selected/used. That is, for the first call the second version larger(const T* a, const T* b) is not even viable as it is more specialized for pointers but the arguments a and b are not pointers.
Case 2
For the second call larger<int>(c, d) only the second version larger(const T* a, const T* b) is viable. That is, here the first version larger(const T& a, const T& b) is not even viable.
